# Plone/portal_workflow - Why can't I add a state to my workflow through zope manage interface?

Tags: plone, zope, plone-4.x

I am making a workflow, starting off with Simple Publication Workflow as the base (copied and pasted it) and renamed it to my_personal_workflow

The id is my_personal_workflow
The title is My Personal Workflow

In my states, I added a state called draft (title is Draft, id is draft) and made that the default state, and I removed the other states.  Currently I am trying to add another state with the id 'awaiting_his_approval', however when I hit Add, instead of creating the state, I am getting a message.

```
We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…

Here is the full error message:

Display traceback as text

Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 72, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 53, in missing_name
    Module ZPublisher.HTTPResponse, line 741, in badRequestError

BadRequest: <h2>Site Error</h2> 
<p>An error was encountered while publishing this resource. </p>     
<p><strong>Invalid request</strong></p> 
The parameter, <em>ids</em>, was omitted from the request.
<p>Make sure to specify all required parameters, and try the request again.</p>
<hr noshade="noshade"/> <p>Troubleshooting Suggestions</p> 

<ul> <li>The URL may be incorrect.</li> 
     <li>The parameters passed to this resource may be incorrect.</li>        
     <li>A resource that this resource relies on may be encountering an error.</li> 
     </ul>
<p>For more detailed information about the error, please refer 
to the error log. </p> <p>If the error persists please contact the site
maintainer. Thank you for your patience. </p>
```

I am not sure why this problem is occurring.  I don't have any other states with the same workflow id.  What can cause this?

I am using Plone 4.3.

Edit:

This is weird.  I hit the back button and submitted it again.  The state was added.  I know its not the case, but it seems to be random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little flaw of the form: The error occurs when hitting the Return-key after entering the state-id in the input-field. It does not occur, when clicking the "Add"-button.

Comment: Right, BTW the whole workflow ZMI started suffering of issues recently, especially on Plone 5

Comment: I see what's happening.  When I hit the Return-key, it was selecting the Delete button.
Thank you.  That would explain why I sometimes got it to work because I was alternating between selecting "Add" and hitting Return. lol